# Using Amazon AWS, but with different web hosting company

Tags: web, amazon-web-services, routes, host

I am thinking to use Amazon's AWS for my end users, does it mean I have to move my company web site from the existing web host to Amazon?
Is it possible that I still use the existing web host, but route all AWS service traffic thru. my existing web site?

Comment: Your large edit of the question, makes it essentially an entirely different one. Instead I suggest you revert it to previous state and post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible, you can refer to the documentation that Amazon provides here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 0):

No - use can use your normal URLs. Adjust your DNS - e.g. use Amazon Route 53.

Actually - I suggest, that you try it out. It costs nothing - you can do it under the AWS free tier (http://aws.amazon.com/free/)